# Behaviour of "Reputation changes" button changes when page is fully loaded

Tags: bug, user-interface

The "reputation changes" button in the top right corner of the page (the one captioned "You have new reputation changes" assuming that's the case), has a behaviour that depends on whether or not the page you're on is fully loaded:

- If you click it before the page is fully loaded, it causes navigation to a different page, `https://stackexchange.com/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=reputation`
- If you click it after the page is fully loaded, it just opens a little popup window without navigation away from the current page

I find this behaviour very jarring, because I often click on the button expecting the second behaviour to happen, only to realize that - whoops! - the page wasn't actually fully loaded, and I've just triggered an expensive page navigation to a completely different page form which I now have to navigate back.

Is this difference in the two behaviours really necessary? Can the button be made to have the second behaviour (show the popup), and never navigate to a new page, even when clicked on before the page is fully loaded?

Comment: The second behavior depends on JavaScript. It's traditional to run the JavaScript only after the page has finished loading (to speed up load time for the rest of the page). The point of the first behavior is to make the page "hardier". If the JavaScript fails to load or has a bug, you'll still be able to reach a useful page.

Comment: This is also the case for the other icons except the help menu.